# Gradle - How can I do flyway migrations in itest sourceset

Tags: gradle, integration-testing, flyway

EDIT: question solved because I noticed that:

- `itest` not running because `test` phase has some errors so the next step `itest` will not proceed
- `itest` also applies migrations, I have checked carefully the log and can confirm that. I search in `itest` log `flyway` and I saw that.

So the question is a mistake. Sorry.

I have sourceset:

- main
- test
- itest

And `itest` is defined like:(`project/gradle/integration.gradle`)

```
sourceSets {
    itest {
        java.srcDir file('src/itest/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/itest/resources')
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
        compileClasspath += configurations.testCompileClasspath
        compileClasspath += configurations.testRuntimeClasspath
        runtimeClasspath += output + compileClasspath + test.output
        annotationProcessorPath += configurations.testAnnotationProcessor
    }
}

task itest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs the integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.itest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.itest.runtimeClasspath

    mustRunAfter test
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I run `gradle test itest` I see migrations applied, but when I run `gradle itest` they are not. I understand that if I force `itest` executed after `test`, like what it is now, I can ensure; but there are time I only want to run `itest`.

How can I change this script?

Comment: How are you applying migrations for the normal test task? You will probably have to do the same for itest.

Comment: Yes but in the `build.gradle` this is no `flywayMigrate` part. So I don't know how.

Comment: @BjørnVester Sorry I forgot to mention that I am with Spring Boot, so there is `FlywayAutoconfiguration`.

Answer (score 0):

The Migrate task run is always because of the `gradle flywayMigrate` task triggered.

Maybe some plugin changed the default setting to make `test` task dependsOn the `flywayMigrate`.

So if you want your own task to trigger the `flywayMigrate`, you can do like this:

```
itest.dependsOn flywayMigrate  

// reference:
clean.dependsOn flywayRepair  # To repair the Flyway metadata table
build.dependsOn flywayMigrate  # To migrate the schema to the latest version
```

Comment: Tried that but the parsing of `integration.gradle` fails. Seems that the task is not defined anywhere. BTW I am with Spring Boot

Comment: I meant `flywayMigrate` is not found/defined anywhere.

Comment: gradle flyway plugin is not used here, that's why flywayMigrate is not available. But I want to do `Flyway.migrate()` just as Spring Boot do in `FlywayAutoconfiguration`, because `flywayMigrate` always requires `flyway {}` properties like `user`, `url` and `password`, and I don't see an easy way to read these properties from `application.yml` specially when they are profile-specific.

Comment: @WesternGun there are spring boot automatically run Flyway docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html, and they provided the example project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v2.1.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-flyway

Comment: sorry, but that is not my case: I want to migrate flyway in another sourceset, `itest`, neither `main` either `test`. The example is a very basic one and does not contain more than `main` and `test` sourcesets.